# PyQt5 read blob from sql database into pixmap

Tags: python, pyqt, blob, pyqt5, qpixmap

I am trying to retrieve and display image that is stored as blob in on sql server.
Below is a snippet of my query that works for every field except user_pic (blob).

```
 str_user_profile = "SELECT first_name, last_name, nick_name, username, password, user_pic FROM  ut_users WHERE (user_id LIKE '" + user_id + "')"

        qr_user_profile = QSqlQuery()
        qr_user_profile.exec(str_user_profile)
        try:
            while qr_user_profile.next():
                first_name = str(qr_user_profile.value(0)).strip()
                last_name = str(qr_user_profile.value(1)).strip()
                nickname = str(qr_user_profile.value(2)).strip()
                username = str(qr_user_profile.value(3)).strip()
                pwd = str(qr_user_profile.value(4)).strip()
                img_data = qr_user_profile.value(5)
```

Once I get a data I know how to convert it pixmap.

```
          pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
          pixmap.loadFromData(img_data)
```

But I am obviously doing something wrong retrieving binary data. From my experience  in vb.net I know that binary data can be converted to the stream and then to image. It's my understanding that loadFromData will do that.

Any help, guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What format does the image have?

Comment: the original image is either jpg or png that is stored as blob on sql server

Comment: what is the output of print(img_data)?

Comment: print(img_data) returns:  b''

Comment: then you're not getting data, that's the real problem.

Comment: I gather that. I think I there is something wrong in retrieving it. They way data is recorded is;  db.open ()
            with open (  fileName, 'rb' ) as stream:
                 blob = stream.read ()
            qr_user_pic = QSqlQuery ()
            qr_user_pic.prepare ( "UPDATE  ut_users SET user_pic = :ImageData WHERE (user_id = :UserId)")
            qr_user_pic.bindValue ( ":ImageData", blob )
            qr_user_pic.bindValue ( ":UserId", user_id )
            qr_user_pic.exec ()
            db.close ()

Comment: What is the driver you use to connect?

Comment: Sorry the code looks like a mess.   db.setDatabaseName ( 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;'

Comment: Are you sure the blob is in the database?

Comment: The field says: <Binary data>

Comment: SQL Server has a utility software that allows you to obtain the data, use it and tell me if the image is saved or not. On the other hand in the connection you must use the following code: `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase(SOME_NAME)`, what value do you use in SOME_NAME?

Comment: db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase ( 'QODBC' )

Comment: according to the documentation does not support the BLOB data type: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-types.html#odbc-data-types

Comment: wow. thanks. I will try with MySQL instead.